# Display IE window using WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I am working on a program that loads a webpage and calculates the load time. I want to give my program a URL and have it open an IE window at that page.

At first I was using Process.Start() to open the IE window, which works, but doesn't give me access to the WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted function. I am trying to create the IE window using a WebBrowser instance but I can't get the IE window to display.

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WebBrowserTest
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            WebBrowser IETestBrowser;
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                IETestBrowser = new WebBrowser();
                IETestBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
                IETestBrowser.Visible = true;
                IETestBrowser.DocumentCompleted += ietb_DocumentCompleted;
            }

            private void LoadPageBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                IETestBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
                IETestBrowser.Show();
                TextDescriptionLbl.Text = "Loading Page...";
            }

            private void ietb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                TextDescriptionLbl.Text = "Done!";
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works, and the DocumentCompleted event is triggered properly. I want the webpage to be visibly displayed in an IE window. How do I get the WebBrowser to draw on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    IETestBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    IETestBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
    IETestBrowser.Visible = true;
    IETestBrowser.DocumentCompleted += ietb_DocumentCompleted;

    //Add the WebBrowser Control to the form
    IETestBrowser.Left = 100;
    IETestBrowser.Top = 100;
    this.Controls.Add(IETestBrowser);
}
```